# `null` returned in groovy counter using while (soapui groovyscript)

Tags: groovy, soapui, groovyscriptengine

The below code returns a `null` at the end of the list, which i'm sure is going to give me issues later on. Does anyone know why? I'm sure I'm not understanding something about how this language works :(

```
def loop(){
    c=51
    while (c!=0){
        log.info c
        c--
    }
}
log.info loop()
...................................
Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:4
Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:3
Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:2
Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:1
Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:null
```

Comment: Your `loop()` method returns null, so when you do `log.info loop()` you log the output from `loop()` method which is null and you see something like `Mon Oct 08 11:46:06 CAT 2018:INFO:null`. If you use `log.info()` inside `loop()` method, than you can simply call `loop()` instead `log.info loop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code look like , you should have 'log.info c' before this 'c--', could you please provide full groovy file ?

```
def loop(){
    c=51
    while (c!=0){
        log.info c
        c--        
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, admittedly that does work better, since i see 51 and not 0 now. But i do still see null right at the end after 1. I have updated the script so far but that is the extent of the script (so far lol)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment from @szymon-stepniak, simply dont call the log.info:

```
def loop(){
    c=51
    while (c!=0){
        log.info c
        c--        
    }
}
loop()
```